# Multiple media queries for different screen sizes

Tags: css, screen, media

I'm trying to set different image sizes according to the screen resolution, some of them work and some don't. Here's my Code:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {#gallery-1 img {width:375px;}} // for 1280px screens 
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1439px){#gallery-1 img {width:375px;}} // for 1366px screens 
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (max-width: 1599px) {#gallery-1 img {width:428px;}} // for 1440px screens 
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) and (max-width: 1919px) {#gallery-1 img {width:434px;}} // for 1600px screens 
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {#gallery-1 img {width:540px;}} // for 1920px screens
```

The code is not working at all for the 1366px and 1280px x 600px screen. 1280px x 960px works with the code for the 1366px. 1280px x 1024 works with the code for the 1440px. Can anybody please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

you don't need to set a maxwidth on your media queries as the next media query overrides it anyway. Try this:

```
#gallery-1 img {
    width:375px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
    #gallery-1 img {width:375px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    #gallery-1 img {width:428px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1600px) {
    #gallery-1 img {width:434px;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    #gallery-1 img {width:540px;}
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and worked fine for me! I've tested in tree different pcs with different resolutions and they all worked. but my client says it doesn't work for him, even though his screen resolution it's the same as mine. I think I'll have to find another solution for this. but thanks a lot for your reply!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1366px) {
/* Styles go here */
}
```

Use media query differently like

```
@media (max-width: 1366px) and (min-width: 1441px) {
/* Styles go here */
}
```

this thing will specifically call out in which limit which styles should be applied.